# Duplication of elements from a data frame

Tags: r, duplicates, dataframe, rep

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = c("a", "b", "c", 1, 2, 3), 
                      ncol = 2,
                      nrow = 3,
                      byrow = FALSE))

> x
  V1 V2
1 a  1
2 b  2
3 c  3
```

Lets say I want to duplicate element x[1,2] four times, element x[2,2] six times and element x[3,2] five times and save them all in a new data frame.

```
> v
  V1
  1
  1
  1
  1
  2
  2
  ...
```

I know I could do it by using `rep`, but i'm wondering if there is a more comfortable way.

Comment: It sounds like you might have a more general requirement, but the way the question is currently phrased I would you will receive many specific answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another alternative

```
data.frame(v=rep(as.numeric(x[,2]), c(4,6,5)))
```

If you want to keep the factors, then omit `as.numeric(·)`

```
data.frame(v=rep(x[,2], c(4,6,5)))
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like

```
TheseRows <- c(1, 2, 3)
NManyReps <- c(4, 6, 5)
x[, 2][ do.call(rep, list(TheseRows, NManyReps)) ]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But why do you use `x[, 2]`. I've just tried `do.call(rep, list(TheseRows, NManyReps))` and received basically the same result. What is the difference?

Comment: Try on a more complex `x` and see why